# Keep the order of tabbar tabs in Emacs after restart

Tags: emacs, tabbar

Tabbar is great. It adds tabs on emacs. I loaded it with

```
(require 'tabbar)
(tabbar-mode t)
```

The only issue that I have is that when emacs reloads the desktop on restart, the tabs are reordered. Would you please tell me if there is any way to have the desktop save process save the order of tabs as well? I have tried this and it didn't work.

```
(desktop-save-mode 1)
(require 'saveplace)
(setq-default save-place t) 
;(setq history-length 5500)
(add-to-list 'desktop-globals-to-save 'tabbar-drag-tab)
;(add-to-list 'desktop-globals-to-save 'tabbar-current-tabset)
;(add-to-list 'desktop-globals-to-save 'tabbar-tabsets)
;(add-to-list 'desktop-globals-to-save 'tabbar-tabs)

;(add-to-list 'desktop-globals-to-save 'tabbar-buffer-tabs)
;(add-to-list 'desktop-globals-to-save 'tabbar--buffers)
;(add-to-list 'desktop-globals-to-save 'tabbar--buffer-show-groups)
;(add-to-list 'desktop-globals-to-save 'tabbar-current-tabset)
;(add-to-list 'desktop-globals-to-save 'tabbar-tab-label)
;(add-to-list 'desktop-globals-to-save 'tabbar-select-tab)
;(add-to-list 'desktop-globals-to-save 'tabbar-help-on-tab)
;(add-to-list 'desktop-globals-to-save 'tabbar-button-label)
;(add-to-list 'desktop-globals-to-save 'tabbar-home)
;(add-to-list 'desktop-globals-to-save 'tabbar-home-help)
```

Comment: The original poster is *perhaps* using a combination of `tabbar.el` -- https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/tabbar -- and `tabbar-ruler.el` -- https://github.com/mlf176f2/tabbar-ruler.el -- the latter is what offers the ability to drag tabs.  It is also possible that the original poster is using a fork of the original `tabbar.el` by David Ponce, which *could* be https://github.com/dholm/tabbar by David Holm -- however, this is a guess.  There is no built-in support for restoration of the order of tabs when Emacs restarts, and a custom solution would be required in order to answer this question.